# Determining Virginia Capital-Gains on Collectible Cards

Tags: united-states, taxes, capital-gains-tax, virginia, collectibles

How do I determine what the capital-gains tax is on an item like Collectible Cards, in the state of Virginia? (one-time sale of cards older than a year, not a businessman). Additionally, how does this "interact" with the U.S. Federal capital-gains tax (which as far as I can tell, will be 28%).

It's been surprisingly hard to find this out. The little I've seen, seems to indicate that VA follows the US tax-rates on things like that, which would mean the total tax would be 56%? Ouch...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Virginia long-term capital gains are taxed like any other income, with a maximum rate of 5.75%, so your maximum combined rate is 33.75%.